# Laravel sail: login as root or create an root user

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I am using sail and trying to use the shell as root, which is not possible.
Switching to user root asks for a password, which is not know to me.

I tried to change the dockerfile:

```
ARG WWWROOTGROUP
RUN groupadd --force -g $WWWROOTGROUP sailRoot
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g $WWWROOTGROUP -u 1337 sailRoot

RUN usermod -aG sudo sail
RUN usermod -aG sudo sailRoot
```

I tried to add a new user and give him and the standard sail user root privileges, but it doesnt work.
The sailRoot user isn't available inside the container. Of course I rebuild the container with that dockerfile.
The changed dockerfile gets executed correctly as far as I can tell.

Does anybody know how to change the user to root with sail?

What I want to do is to install imagemagick into the container.
I already add "apt-get install imagemagick imagemagick-doc" to the dockerfile aswell, but its not installed inside the container. If you know how to do that, I would really appreaciate it!

Thanks.

Comment: How about removing the [existing useradd](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/runtimes/8.0/Dockerfile#L46) and groupadd? Bacause afaik the default user is root. no need to add root.

Comment: @onlineThomas Hey, I tried it, but the sail user still gets created. I think sail is doing this by default.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just use:
`sail root-shell`

Or an alias: `sail root-bash`

For more information, you can type `sail help` (in recent editions of Laravel Sail) or review the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/bin/sail).

Comment: Thanks dude, saved the day.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have the problem that this command does not seem to exist while using sail: vendor/bin/sail root-shell
No such command: root_shell - Do you know what to do?

Comment: You should be able to see all available sail commands by typing: `./vendor/bin/sail help` from within your application's directory.

Comment: Thank you @w5m, added it to the original post. Back when Laravel Sail was new, the help command wasn't available.